# Angular ng-options comprehension expression usage inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Could anybody help me with the comprehension expression for the ng-options?

I'm trying to use ng-options inside the ng-repeat iteration over the complex object. 
The usual comprehension expression

```
n.optionid as n.optionname for n in options
```

does not work for some reason. No exceptions occur.
Here is the plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HiU7OCM9kVUIrgxY0AZc?p=preview

Comment: I think you may have linked the wrong plunker?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options is an object and not an array, so the syntax that you are currently using is wrong.

According to the documentation of [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select), the syntax for an object should be one of the following:

```
label for (key , value) in object
select as label for (key , value) in object
label group by group for (key, value) in object
select as label group by group for (key, value) in object
```

For example, you could use :

```
ng-options="opt.optionid as opt.optionname for (key,opt) in variant.options"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your options object to be an array:

```
options : [
         {
          optionid : 123,
          optionname : "some name"
        },
         {
          optionid : 789,
          optionname : "some name 2"
        }
      ]
```